# Add extra variable in annotation rooting with symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to add an extra variable "type"
so i do multiple root in annotation.
then i try this

```
/**
 * @Route("/Theme/{id}/{type}", name="theme_show")
 * @Route("/Theme/{id}", name="theme_show")
 */
public function show($id, $type = null, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){
```

and the return

```
 return $this->render('blog/show.html.twig', [
                'type' => $type,
            ]);
```

and this my button to go at this function

```
<a class="btn btn-dark btn-block" href="{{ path('theme_show', {'id' : theme.id, 'type' : 'question'})}}" role="button">Question</a>
```

and this my url when i try to change page

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Theme/5?type=question
```

but when i dump the content of type in this url i find =  `null`

i also try with a unique rooting annotation

```
        /**
         * @Route("/Theme/{id}/{type}", name="theme_show")
         */
        public function show($id, $type, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){
```

and i have this error

```
No route found for "GET /Theme/5" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Theme/5?type=idee")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are using doesn't match the route.

Your URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Theme/5?type=question
```

Correct URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Theme/5/question
```

Route

```
* @Route("/Theme/{id}/{type}", name="theme_show")
```

If you want to use query parameters as you do in your URL. You'll have to retrieve it from the request.

```
$type = $request->query->get('type');
```

Next, you have two routes with the same name. I'm pretty sure this is not valid even if it is used for the same method. If you run `php bin/console debug:router`, you'll see that only the latest is showing up.

So either you change the name of one of the routes and use your pattern `/Theme/{id}/{type}` or you use query parameter like explained and get rid of the route with 'type'.

Comment: i just do that and it work : $type = $request->query->get('type');